# how to explicity set the request method as post and assign post data

Tags: php, post

is there a way in PHP to set the request method as a `POST`? after setting the request method as `POST`, id like to programmatically assign the post data to be sent.

i dont want to use curl, i want a header redirect. i imagine i need to set a response code? what is the post response code?

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron not quite as that uses curl. i want to actually execute a redirect

Comment: You mean you want to redirect to a page with post data being sent along with the redirect?

Comment: You can't just do a `header("Location")` when you're working with post data.